# How to call an m-script from .tlc file

Tags: matlab, simulink, rtw

I have a requirement to call an m script when the build button is clicked after selecting a target in real time workshop. Can anyone suggest, how this can be accomplished ?
Also I have to pass the name of the simulink model in this m script. Is there a function to extract the name of the current simulink model?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Would PostCodegenCommand (http://www.mathworks.com/help/rtw/ug/customizing-post-code-generation-build-processing.html) or RTW hooks (http://www.mathworks.com/help/rtw/ug/customizing-the-target-build-process-with-the-stf-make-rtw-hook-file.html) work for you?

Comment: Hi, Thanks very much i was able to add some m scripts in the rtw_hook files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`bdroot`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/bdroot.html) or [`gcs`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/gcs.html) to get the name of the Simulink model. Not sure about calling a MATLAB script as part of the build.

Answer (score 2):

This is typically achieved using RTW Hooks.  To see a description of the process select the first link that appears after executing the following:

> > docsearch('Customize Build Process with STF_make_rtw_hook File')